# How can I display the error?

Tags: php, html

Currently this just displays 'Error':

```
    if(@mail($email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
    echo 'Message sent!'; 
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

How can I display the actual error?

Thanks

Comment: *"How can I display the error?"* - Start by removing the `@` symbol and use error reporting.

Comment: remove the `@` too see the response error from mail()

Comment: ...then come and tell us what the error is. In a nutshell: your code failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail being a possible duplicate.

Comment: @ is the best way to hide the dust under the carpet ^^

Comment: @OldPadawan *Hehe*, so true. Seems there's a lot of dust laying around these days; under the 'ol Magic Stack Carpet, as it were. +1

Comment: @Fred-ii- long time ago, if a far far galaxy... error_reporting(E_ALL); + ini_set('display_errors', 1); + $stmt->error_list;
+ $stmt->get_warnings(); changed my life :)

Comment: @OldPadawan [You mean, this one?...](http://media.moddb.com/cache/images/mods/1/14/13819/thumb_620x2000/Video.mp4.jpg)

Comment: @Fred-ii- :D this one and 1st order too ! [do, or do not ! there is not try](https://b43i.imgup.net/yoda42db.png) May the force be with you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Average Level Code

```
ob_start();
$result=mail($email,$email_subject,$email_content);
$err=ob_get_clean();
if($result) {
   echo 'Message sent!'; 
} else {
   echo "ERROR: {$err}";
}
```

Why

- You not have to throw and catch an real exception
- You can write the error on the page where you need it
- simple fix, without need of extra stuff

But you have to set `error_reporting()` to an proper level, if the errors from `mail()` will still not show up.